# Anyone knows how this rare "angelic" headvoice/falsetto is achieved?

Tags: theory, technique, voice, learning, falsetto

So I randomly scrolled Youtube and found this cover:

At 1.06, I'm wondering..
how is this "angelic" head voice achieved? If it's just airy/breathy head voice, then how is it achieved?

Comment: Whether she is improvising _ad lib_ or performing a fixed melody that she has practiced carefully is possibly unknowable without asking her or having recordings of other performances to compare.  In any event, it's an entirely different question from the one about the manner of vocal production.

Comment: Welcome to Music.SE. Please edit your post to focus on only one question, as per our site guidance. See [about] and [ask]